# Update size in playstore is same as download size

Tags: android, google-play

I have my app in Play Store which is created with ionic framework, a hybrid code.
My first beta version, is about 10MB download size.

However, I notice I have mistakes in a few words and icons, and I corrected it without make any other changes. It is very simple changed.

When I upload and release as 1.0.1 version in beta, the update size of the app is 10.3MB. It is just as big as the download size.

Why this happen? Isn't it the update size should be much smaller than download size?Since I just make a simple changed.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I don't really understand. Is it because of I use ionic? As I notice, apps like Whatsapp will have a smaller update size after you have intsall the app. But mine didn't. My updates need download another 10MB, just same as new download. Why the others app can just download a small portion of the changed?

Comment: Actually I misspoke. There is differential updates available but it may be Ionic, it may be something else that makes the files not match.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, Thanks. Do you know how I know is the mismatched issues or is due to ionic. Contact google play store but no response at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Play does offer delta / differential updates** to reduce update sizes.

The update size is determined by Google's algorithms, however I am not sure if the Ionic Framework does interfere with these.

You could check the differences of your APKs with the [**compare tool provided by Google**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html#compare_apk_files). Maybe this could make it clear why your updates aren't released as differentials only.

**Further resources:**

- [Android Developer Blog about delta updates](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/improvements-for-smaller-app-downloads.html)
- [Tracking app update sizes](https://medium.com/google-developers/tracking-app-update-sizes-1a1f57634f7b)

Comment: is the google play automatically compare and only updated the difference or there  are settings I need to take acre of?

Comment: It's part of the default update process, you cannot enable / disable it.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Google Play generates differentials based on demand. If very few users are requesting updates then the delta update might not be generated. I suspect your app is not popular enough yet to make the differential update worth generating.

Comment: Hi, Nick. Is hybrid code app also have the differentials to download app feature or just limited to native android? Besides, what is the downloads needed to consider popular and Google Play will generates the differentials?